# Java: Concurrency inside ActionListener.actionPerformed

Tags: java, concurrency, actionlistener, synchronized, volatile

today I started deal with concurrency in Java (probably that was bad idea...)

I read some articles about it. At the beginning I understood it but now I am confused...

I'm going straight to the point. Suppose we have this class

```
public class Test implements ActionListener
{
    private boolean bool;

    public void process()
    {
        if (bool)
            // ...

        return bool;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // We can suppose that this method belongs to JButton or so...
        // And if I am not wrong then this method is fired in EDT, so it means it runs in
        // other thread (Event Dispatch Thread) in contrast with this class... So there are
        // two threads...

        bool = ... ? true : false;
    }

    // ...
}
```

My confusion:

In **actionPerformed()** we modify the value of property **bool** and in the same time we can access the property inside **process()** (again if I am not wrong)... For me it seems that there can occur to some error or so... My solution is that property **bool** should be **volatile** or method **process()** should be tagged as **synchronized** and statement

```
bool = ... ? true : false;
```

should be as:

```
synchronized (this)
{
    bool = ... ? true : false;
}
```

This is little primitive example, but we can consider **bool** property as Object, String, etc... and in **actionPerformed()** we will set it to null and in process() will be thrown a NullPointerException for example...

What you think? I want to know why anyone use synchronizing inside listeners... I have not found anyone...

Thanks

Regards
brolinko

**EDIT #1:** **process()** is never called within EDT... When I create an instance of Test for example in **main()** method then the instance runs inside a thread as main() and in main() I can call the process() ... So there are two threads in this case if I am not wrong...

Comment: do you expect the `process()` method to be used outside of gui code?

Comment: By the way, regardless of concurrency and regardless of what `…` actually contains, code like `bool = …? true: false;` smells. Just write `bool = …;`. Adding `? true: false` after an expression is usually a sign that the programmer has missed the fundamental point of the `boolean` type: it doesn’t need to be converted to `true` or `false`, it always is either of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not wrong, if a variable is used by two or more threads, writes should be made visible by using the appropriate memory barriers (synchronized/volatile/java.util.concurrent).

In this case though, the question is: is `process()` not also called from the EDT? If it is, there are no multiple threads to talk about and hence the code works, albeit dangerously unsafe.

<strike>**Update:** You're saying `process()` isn't called from the EDT. Your code will still happen to work because although you don't put a memory barrier on your write, [the implementation of the EDT does](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/awt/EventDispatchThread.java#184). In theory, relying on this is a dangerous idea because there's no guarantee this will stay this way. In practice, there are so many brittle AWT applications out there that it's unlikely to change.</strike> (As pointed out by @jtahlborn, this barrier still only applies to calls from within the EDT)

Comment: that memory barrier won't do anything unless the other thread is _also_ synchronizing with the event loop.  so volatile/synchronization _must_ be used in this code for correct visibility.

Comment: @jtahlborn Hmm, that's true. But coincidentally it works...at least most of the time. :)

Comment: yeah, that's the way most concurrency issues are.  they work... must of the time... until they break under stress in production.

Answer (score 2):

The Java memory model and the Java multithreading rules apply to all classes and threads. The fact that your class implements ActionListener is irrelevant.

If two threads access a shared variable and you expect writes by one thread to be visible by reads from the other threads, then some kind of synchronization must be used to access the shared variable (synchronized access, make the variable volatile, or use a thread-safe object like an AtomicBoolean).